# To include a resource ID in the payload or to derive from URI

Tags: rest, resources

Designing an API, we've come up against the question of whether a PUT payload should contain the ID of the resource being updated.

This is what we currently have:

`PUT /users/123 Payload: {name: "Adrian"}`

Our route code extracts the ID from the URI and continues on with the update.

The first users of our API are questioning why we don't allow ID in the payload:

`PUT /users/123 Payload: {id: 123, name: "Adrian"}`

The reason we didn't allow it is because the ID is duplicated, in the payload and URI.

Thinking about this some more, we are coupling the resource to the URI.

If the URI doesn't have the ID, the payload will need to be amended:

`PUT /no/id/here Payload: {name: "Adrian"} < What user???`

Are there any reasons not to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are *supposed* to couple the Uniform **Resource** Identifier to the **resource**.

When REST is implemented with HTTP, you use GET to retrieve the current value of the resource and PUT to set a new value. The GET does not have a payload, so the resource has to be identified by the URI. And the PUT is logically done to the same URI and the payload should look exactly as what you want the next GET to return.

You can use POST to different URI, but it would only make less sense as it would be unnecessarily asymmetrical to the GET. POST to common URI could only make sense for creating new resources (`POST /users/new`, payload: `{name: "Adrian"}`, response `{id: 345, name: "Adrian"}`), but that's *not idempotent* and therefore **should be avoided** <del>if you are striving for REST</del>¹. Instead you should reserve ID with one call and then use PUT to set the new ID; that is fault-tolerant, because if the first request fails, the ID reservation can time out eventually and the `PUT` is idempotent. Or use client-generated UUID.

---

¹ The definition of REST does not say anything about idempotence, so I can't really claim it is not REST if you have non-idempotent operations. That does not change the fact that sticking to idempotent requests makes things more reliable without complicating them and is therefore recommended.

Comment: As far as I know a POST request does not have to be idempotent. So I see no problem with posting to `/users` (no need to add 'new').

Comment: thanks for your reply. I see that it is a nice feature to have idempotency for all requests but who says this is required for a REST API? Certainly many APIs that call themselves RESTful allow non-idempotent POST requests (especially when the server generates ids for new resources). But even if you apply a very strict definition of REST, I don't see which architectural constraint ist violated with non idempotent POSTs like the example above.

Comment: I can certainly image POST requests that violate a constraint. I just don't see why posting a resource into a collection and letting the server decide on its id is a violation of REST constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57535/discussion-between-lex82-and-jan-hudec).

Comment: The whole idea of POST is not to be idempotent....

Comment: @EralpB, idea of POST is to *allow* non-idempotence, but that does not make it good idea (I updated the answer a bit, because REST does not actually speak about this, so it is not that it is not REST, it simply just isn't good idea).

Answer (score 6):

> Thinking about this some more, we are coupling the resource to the
>   URI.
>
> If the URI doesn't have the ID, the payload will need to be amended:
>
> PUT /no/id/here Payload: {name: "Adrian"} < What user???
>
> Are there any reasons not to?

The answer to this question depends on whether you want to allow the client to change the ID?

If the client can change the ID, via a PUT, then the URI for the resource will change, and you should provide a 301 Moved Permanently any time a resource accesses the old URI.

So for example you start with a resource at

```
/users/123
```

and the client PUTs the following onto the resource

```
{id: 222, name: "Adrian"}
```

the resource has been updated and its URI is now

```
/users/222
```

The `Location` field in the PUT response should contain the new URI, and if you go to `/users/123` you should get a `301` response with the Location field pointing to the new `/users/222` resource.

In most cases though you don't actually want the client to be able to change the ID, as this can get pretty messy pretty quickly. In that case the ID is something only the server can change, and you should leave it out of the PUT body, as the client cannot update this state.

If you PUT a require to a different URI on the same resource, say

```
/users/adian_lync
```

then if that resource does not exist the server should create it and create and ID when it is doing it

Comment: The reason for us questioning the placement of the ID in the payload was due to Backbone.js passing the ID in a PUT request by default. We can stop it from happening, but now I want to know why that's the default behaviour.

Comment: Afraid I'm not familiar with Backbone.js. Seem unnecessary if the ID is included in the URL as well. Perhaps an oversight on the part of the devs

Comment: I disagree that PUT /users/123 would remap to /users/222. The resource identity is permanent. Next call to /users/123 should return the record that was updated to 222, to remain RESTful.

Comment: @CompEng88 REST is stateless from the client's perspective, nothing is assumed to be permanent including URLs, and there is a whole mechanism in HTTP (which is RESTful) for moving resources and updating clients as to the new location. That is what the `Location` header is about and the `301` and `308` status codes are for. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#status.301